# Footable css class adds a comma

Tags: css, asp.net, gridview, footable

I have applied footable CSS class on a ASP.net gridview to develop a responsive table. The gridview contains a textbox (template) field which shows in detail row (in collapsed mode) when viewed on a tablet or phone. The problem is when the page is reloaded after entering a value to this textbox it has the initial value with a coma appended to it.

Ex: when user enters 'test' in the gridview textbox field and submit, the textbox contains the value ',test'. If submited again it will show the value as ',test,test'.

If submitted without any value in the textbox, it will display like ',,'
This happens only  in collapsed view, when the gridview is viewed from desktop (fully expanded) it's working fine.
Hope I can get help on fixing this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up handling through code behind.

```
            TextBox tbName = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtName");
            string txtname = tbName.Text;
            int index1 = txtname.LastIndexOf(',');

            string memName = "";

            if (index1 != -1)
            {
                index1++;
                memName = tbName.Text.Substring(index1);
                tbName.Text = memName;
            }
```